How does the Catholic church interpret Matthew 1:25?
Matthew 1:25 (NIV):

But he did not consummate their marriage until she gave birth to a son. And he gave him the name Jesus.


καὶ (and) οὐκ (not) ἐγίνωσκεν (he knew) αὐτήν (her) ἕως (until) οὗ (she) ἔτεκε (gave birth) υἱόν (a son) καὶ (and) ἐκάλεσεν (he called) τὸ (the) ὄνομα (name) αὐτοῦ (of him) Ἰησοῦν (Jesus)

This verse could be read to imply that Mary and Joseph consummated their marriage after Mary gave birth to Jesus.  How do the traditions of the Catholic church interpret this verse?  Specifically, I am interested in a teaching of the Catholic church itself (not a Catholic apologist) that explicitly argues against interpreting this verse in that manner, if any exists.
I did search before I asked this and I found several questions relating to this verse (unsurprisingly!) but I could not find one that asked this exact question.  Even so, I do apologise if this is a duplicate.

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for. The doctrine of Mary's Perpetual Virginity requires Catholics not to interpret this verse as implying that Mary and Joseph consummated their marriage. It's as simple as the fact that that doctrine exists. Catholic Apologists are going to go into more detail, and it's easier to just link to them because they have done exhaustive work on this question. Is the answer to your question simply that the doctrine of the Perpetual Virginity of Mary exists?

I'm not Catholic, but I'm curious about the question. From a practical perspective, had Joseph and Mary enjoined intercourse before the birth, every human over the last 2,000+ years could have claimed without compunction the virgin birth was a fake.  The statement in the verse had to be made and be true or the miraculous nature of Christ's birth would be rendered moot. Maybe a better question is how Catholicism interprets Matt 13:55, but Matt 27:56 and John 19:25 seem to have that covered.

@jaredad7 I understand Catholic doctrine requires a specific interpretation of this verse.  So, if the answer is "no, there's no specific comment on this verse" that's absolutely fine.  I'm only curious if the church did say something specifically about it.

@JBH I'm not sure I entirely follow your comment.  If it helps, the reason I ask about this specific verse is because of the word "until" -- in English, if we say "Mary did not do X until Y", it implies she did do X after Y.  I understand that the Greek word can be interpreted differently, and for Catholics must be interpreted differently, but my question is not "how could this verse be interpreted to fit Catholic doctrine?", but rather, what specifically (if anything) the church said about it.  Does that help explain the question?

That does help. Following @jaredad7's recommendation of looking up some of the apologists, I quickly found two: 1, 2. I could hope someone answers more fully because the arguments made in those articles are odd. For example, they list a bunch of uses of "until" a terminal period (death or the end of time) and since the action didn't proceed past that terminal period obviously(?) it didn't after the birth of Jesus.

@JBH in the first article, Trent Horn talks about a woman not giving birth until her death, and Jesus being with His disciples until the end of the age, and makes the point that we do not infer from either of these uses of the word 'until' that the condition was reversed after that point, and thus we ought not infer from the use of 'until' in Matthew 1:25 that the condition was reversed here, either. Simply, the semantic range of the word used is too broad to conclude what objectors to the perpetual virginity would have us conclude from this passage.

@unixwitch usually the Catholic Church will not give an authoritative interpretation of a certain passage of Scripture, but will only deny certain interpretations. Positive requirement that we must understand Scripture to mean a specific thing is rare (although the literal sense of the text must be retained and understood to be true, broadly construed). Negative requirements are more common. We are not permitted to interpret passages in ways that are contrary to settled dogma.

@jaredad7 I understood the articles, but the verse (Matt 1:25) doesn't say "until her death." It only says until the birth. That's my concern. I don't want to debate beliefs. They are what they are. From my perspective, the virgin birth would be no less virgin or miraculous if Mary consummated her marriage after Christ's birth. What's surprising is using the argument that "until death" can be applied to "until birth" to mean "until death." That seems like stretching to make a point to me. (*shrug*)

@jaredad7 "usually the Catholic Church will not give an authoritative interpretation of a certain passage of Scripture" -- that is understandable, and if you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it, unless someone else knows different (which seems unlikely at this point).

@JBH the argument is just about the word until and what it implies. It doesn't matter what the object of the preposition "until" is. It matters what the semantic range of "until" is.

@jaredad7 Yeah, I get it. It's just surprising to me that the assertion is something along the lines of, "'until' always means to the end of recorded time, even if it's scope is stated in the sentence." Gratefully, both our beliefs converge on the core doctrine: a divine birth.

It is very difficult and perhaps impossible, when placing man made doctrine first, to let the Scripture simply mean what it says, even when it is being quite clear.  This holds true for all denominations and theologies.  If Scripture is not decidedly first, all bets are off.

@JBH They don't have any choice.  The infallible dogmatic statements have them backed into a corner.

@MikeBorden I get that too, but please remember that we're all here to better understand one another, not to judge one another. Let's let God worry about that.

@מרים " in English, if we say "Mary did not do X until Y", it implies she did do X after Y" No, that's not actually always true.

@MikeBorden "It is very difficult and perhaps impossible, when placing man made doctrine first, to let the Scripture simply mean what it says" No, sorry that is your claim. It should go without saying that Catholicism does not consider it a man-made doctrine (and incidentally would consider sola scriptura man-made). In any case, that is irrelevant here. " The infallible dogmatic statements have them backed into a corner" rather, we only define infallibly what we are certain of -- your objections notwithstanding.

@eques I understand your point and I apologise if I phrased this badly.  As I said, I understand that word can be interpreted in different ways and I did not mean to imply any particular interpretation is more correct.  I was only trying to highlight the various ways people might interpret it to place my question in context.

@מרים therein is the problem. The argument against assumes until must imply a change even though it doesn't even in English do so.

Could Consummate mean something different in Jewish marriage law, like she moves into his house? Yes!, here " The second stage of the marriage process is the consummation. It is alternatively termed nissuin, meaning elevation of status, from nassa, coming by carriage from the father's home to the groom's; or chuppah, wedding canopy." from https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/465162/jewish/The-Jewish-Marriage-Ceremony.htm

Questions which ask for an official, positive interpretation of Scripture from a Catholic perspective are usually founded on a wrong premise about Catholic doctrine and exegesis. In general, a Catholic exegete will look first at the doctrines of the Church, then, secondarily, at what the Church Fathers, reputable theologians, and especially saints given the title of "Doctor" have said about the passage. Then, when performing an exegesis of the passage in question, the exegete will take all he has learned from these sources into account.
As such, there is no singular, authoritative teaching from the Catholic Church on how Matthew 1:25 must be interpreted, but She has said some things about how the verse may not be interpreted. For example, on account of the doctrine of Mary's Perpetual Virginity, the Catholic exegete cannot interpret this verse as implying that Mary and Joseph had natural marital relations after the time of Jesus' birth, since that would contradict the dogma of the Church. As for how to reconcile the dogma and the passage, that is left up to theologians and apologists, and these should support their views by analyzing the text in light of what reputable theologians, especially the Church Fathers, have said about it, as well as by performing relevant textual analyses and word studies. The Greek word Heos (translated as "until" in the verse in question) would be especially important to study. A good exegete or apologist would examine how this word is used in the Septuagint and in the rest of the New Testament, including other passages in Matthew, and see if the word's usage accords with the teaching of the Church. As the question asks not to hear from any apologists, I have not linked any, but a cursory search on a site like Catholic Answers (catholic.com) will reveal many articles written by good Catholic theologians on this particular verse.
In general, asking for "the Catholic Church's authoritative interpretation" of a particular verse is not a useful question, as it rests upon a false premise about how Catholics do biblical exegesis.

Thank you for the well-written answer, which I've accepted. When you say "As for how to reconcile the dogma and the passage, that is left up to theologians and apologists", do I understand right that as a general practice, the Catholic church is usually content to simply issue dogma and leave it up to apologists to interpret any possibly conflicting scripture as appropriate?  (I can ask this as a separate question, but I'm hoping it'll be a quick yes or no answer.)

Yes, dogma is usually given by the Church in the form of a formalize papal pronouncement ex cathedra or by an ecumenical council, and then if there are apparent contradictions with Scripture, theologians or apologists will need to work to reconcile the apparent contradictions. This is done properly by beginning with the premise that no actual contradiction can exist, since these forms of Church declarations are infallible (if you want to get into the nuances of infallibility, I'd recommend a second question).

I am curious about that but, for now, my curiousity is satisfied, thank you!  I would upvote your comment (and answer) but apparently I don't have enough "χάρις" on this site to do that yet :-)

@jaredad7 we should clarify that dogma isn't derived independently from Scripture (which is how someone might interpret some of your answer). The Church Fathers placed great emphasis on Scripture.

@eques feel free to edit my answer if you see a better way to phrase things to avoid that potential confusion. Of course the Church and Scripture work in tandem to form doctrines and dogma.
